# How to create animated color transition in react.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have a navbar that changes color when a condition is met, but it happens instantly. Is there a way to make a smooth transition between two colors instead? I mean sth like -webkit-transition (putting it inside style={{...}} doesn't seem to work like in the other cases).

```
      <Navbar className="navbar" style={{backgroundColor: condition? 'red' : 'green'}}>
        <NavbarBrand href="/">Example</NavbarBrand>
         ...

      </Navbar>
```

Comment: don't set by style... set a className, and then, define the transition in css file

Comment: I guess React does add/remove the styles as it is re-rendering the component. Therefore the "transition" is not always there. You could set the "transition: 1s all" in a global CSS, then, the color-switch could work. Hard to say without a working example tho.

Comment: yep! it seems to be a job for css

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set using `transition` or `WebkitTransition` property, in addition to the applied inline style.

Try like this:

```
style={{
  backgroundColor: condition ? "red" : "green",
  transition: "all .5s ease",
  WebkitTransition: "all .5s ease",
  MozTransition: "all .5s ease"
}}
```

I tried creating a `codesandbox` example, have a look:

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-napier-rnveq?fontsize=14

For transition property, refer: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

look to image [look to image ][or look to code]

import React from 'react';

export default () => {
  return

```
backgroundColor: condation ? "truecolor" : "falsecolor",
transition: "all 0.8s ease",
WebkitTransition: "all 0.8s ease",
MozTransition:"all 0.8s ease"
```

}}>You are logged in.
};